# Dynamic Analysis exercise in textbook - answer is surprising

Tags: testing, dynamic, code-analysis

I have the Advanced Software Testing Vol 3 for Technical Test Analysts book, and there's this question on dynamic analysis in Section 4 - Test Techniques, on p.321. Can someone with expertise please, please confirm what they believe the answer to be, because the answer at the back of the book totally surprised me and it's driving me mad! Re-reading the relevant sections of the book hadn't helped either.

```
Consider the following list:
I. Memory loss due to wild pointers
II. Profiling performance characteristics of a system
III. Failure to initialize a local variable
IV. Argument error in Windows 32 API call
V. Incorrect use of a equality operator in a predicate
VI. Failure to place a break in a switch statement
VII. Finding dead code

Which of these are most likely to be found through the use of a dynamic analysis tool?

A. I, III, IV and VII
B. I, II, III, IV and VI
C. I, II and IV
D. II, IV and V
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is A.  Dynamic analysis tools are designed to capture details about a system as it is executing, whereas static analysis tools can analyze source code by itself.

Items `I` and `IV` both deal with memory allocation, which is virtually impossible to analyze statically.  Dynamic analysis can determine when a pointer has been allocated incorrectly, or if the memory allocated to a low-level API call is insufficient to contain the data structures that are returned.

Items `III` and `VII` both deal with issues that may only be found through a small number of code paths.  Dynamic analysis can use a large number of inputs to run through each code path and determine situations in which a variable goes uninitialized, or whether there are some code sections that are never executed (dead code).

Items `V` and `VI` are both logical errors, which would be evident in test results.  Dynamic analysis would not be effective at determining that the logic of a program is correct.  Debuggers and loggers are the best tool to use there.

Item `II` seems a little ambiguous (what is the "system" referred to?) but dynamic analysis generally refers to tools used to find issues, rather than analyze system performance.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately, to add to my confusion, an acquaintance on LinkedIn contacted the book's co-authors, and they have said the answer is actually C (which is what I went for) and that A is an error.

Comment: Justification for NOT choosing A was that, based on the same textbook under Static Analysis / Dynamic Analysis sections, and also in the ISTQB Syllabus, `III` and `VII` are attributed to static tools and techniques. (Plus there's an exercise in the book p.423, on Code Reviews (i.e. a static method), where the author points out variables NOT being initialised. I agree that `II` seems flaky in its description, the books doesn't really justify this; ISTQB syllabus does a little more... in the end it was process of elimination.

Comment: Items `III` and `VII` cover a variety of different cases, some of which may be better handled by one method or the other.  In the case of dead code, for example, code inside an `if (false)` statement is clearly dead, and can be found via static analysis.  But code inside `if (flag)` may be dead if `flag` will always evaluate to false, based on the operating conditions of the system.  Static analysis may not be able to figure this out, but dynamic analysis could note that that code has never been executed over a long-running test.  All in all, it's a very subjective question.

Comment: Thanks @nintendojunkie - subjective questions are a speciality of the ISTQB exam :o)